# Can you render a template in express and then change it when a condition is met?

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
   let x = false
   // function that changes x to true after completing

   res.send('function running')
   if(x) {
     res.send('Function complete')
   }

})
```

I am trying to render a response in express while a function is running. Once it completes, it changes the value of a variable. I want to render a different response once the value of that variable changes. When I tried the above code, I got an error.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Comment: People could help you better with a variety of solutions if you explained the real problem (describe what initial content looks like and then what final content looks like).  As has already been said, you can't call `res.send()` more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `res.send` only once per request. But you can use chunking to send already some HTML to the browser while the function is running and more after it has completed:

```js
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  res.type("html");
  res.write("<p>Running</p>");
  setTimeout(function() {
    res.end("<p>Completed</p>");
  }, 1000);
});
```

(Here, the "function" just consists of waiting 1 second.)